# dask_ml.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler Attribute error

Tags: dask

I've just download dask_ml, and I can't use the preprocessing class.

I first try

```
scaler = dask_ml.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
```

but I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'dask_ml' has no attribute 'preprocessing'
```

Then I tried the following:

```
from dask_ml.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

and I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/var/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/dask_ml/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .data import (  # noqa
File "/var/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-m 
packages/dask_ml/preprocessing/data.py", line 158, in <module>
class QuantileTransformer(skdata.QuantileTransformer):
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.preprocessing.data' has no attribute 
'QuantileTransformer'
```

What does it mean ? And what are your suggestions to make it work.